# Fragment using onCreateView causes Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I tried to access textviews in a fragment it is throwing nullpointer exception. I have declared the variables and initialized it in `onCreateView` after the `View` is inflated. I don't know why it is throwing the error.

Here is my code

```
public class LoginTextHolder extends Fragment {

private View view;
EditText txtUsername;
EditText txtPassword;

public static LoginTextHolder newInstance() {

    return new LoginTextHolder();
}

public LoginTextHolder() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_text_holder, container, false);
    txtUsername = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    txtPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

public String[] giveData() {
    String[] uNp = {"", ""};
    uNp[0] = txtUsername.getText().toString();
    uNp[1] = txtPassword.getText().toString();
    return uNp;
}
}
```

Here is my logcat output

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at akshara.homeshop.fragments.LoginTextHolder.giveData(LoginTextHolder.java:65)
        at akshara.homeshop.activities.LoginActivity.onLoginEventFragmentInteraction(LoginActivity.java:51)
        at akshara.homeshop.fragments.LoginEventHandlers.onClick(LoginEventHandlers.java:76)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I fix this?

Here is my login activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoginEventHandlers.LoginEventFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

@Override
public void onLoginEventFragmentInteraction(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSignIn:
            LoginTextHolder loginTextsFragment = LoginTextHolder.newInstance();

            Log.e("Sony", loginTextsFragment.giveData()[0]);
            Log.e("Sony", loginTextsFragment.giveData()[1]);
            break;
        case R.id.lblSignUp:
            Log.e("Sony", "SignUp");
            break;
    }

}

}
```

Here is the fragment layout

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/loginTextHolderRoot"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:padding="@dimen/holderDefaultPadding"
tools:context="akshara.homeshop.fragments.LoginTextHolder">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
    style="@style/MyDefaultTextBoxStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/defaultWidgetTopMargin"
    android:hint="@string/userName"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
    style="@style/MyDefaultTextBoxStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtUserName"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/defaultWidgetTopMargin"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The first image is from `onCreateView` and the next is from `giveData`:

[image: from give data![][1]]

[image]

Comment: Where are you calling giveData?

Comment: what is "at akshara.homeshop.fragments.LoginTextHolder.giveData(LoginTextHolder.java:65)", post xml layout and did you search SO first?

Comment: @EricS. it is calling from the activity (login activity)

Comment: Please post the code from where 'giveData' code is invoked

Comment: @MarianPaździoch on line 65 it is calling textview for text  ` uNp[0] = txtUsername.getText().toString();`

Comment: If you want more you should post loginactivity and your layouts.

Comment: Does `giveData` know anything else about `txtUsername` and `txtPassword` other than they are `EditText`?

Comment: @BinaryJudy  nothing

Comment: @JayeshElamgodil here it is `public String[] giveData() {
        String[] uNp = {"", ""};
        uNp[0] = txtUsername.getText().toString();
        uNp[1] = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        return uNp;
    }`

Comment: Try initializing `txtUsername` and `txtPassword` to null and then check for null in `giveData` just to be sure you actually have them. Such as `if(txtUsername != null){uNp[0] = txtUsername.getText().toString();}`

Comment: You can always place a debug point in onCreateView() and check if the edittext variables have received values

Comment: @BinaryJudy it is giving null

Comment: If you want more you should post loginactivity and your layouts.

Comment: Are you sure your `view` is being created before you are trying to call `giveData`?

Comment: post all the code needed to check what's wrong!

Comment: @JayeshElamgodil, i added the view and the 2 textviews to watch and it is  showing value in `onCreateView`and null when entering `giveData`. i'll post the screen shots

Comment: Use a fragment manager in your activity to get the instance of the fragment and then call the giveData method

Comment: Where do you add loginTextsFragment to your activity?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch in the layout using fragment tag

Comment: @sony, Your post can attract more attention by simply changing your title. Perhaps something like "Fragment using onCreateView causes Exception". I think your post is informative and certainly I hope others read it too.

Comment: Wait till this informative post gets 1000 views!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved the initialization to `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. It is not safe to call controls in fragments in its `onCreateView()` always call from `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and thank you all for your time

Comment: Thanks for the good info. In a sample project from Google web, it creates the UI views in the override onViewCreated. While onCreateView() only returns the view from the xml inflate, like inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample...

Comment: please put the link to the project, if there is any, so that it will be useful for someone in future

Comment: I added another answer since you asked. You're informative and helpful, so I will try to check your future posts. Thanks for selecting my answers as helpful. Maybe we make a good SO team, my thoughtful friend :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your stacktrace, it looks like you're calling giveData too soon. You initialize

```
EditText txtUsername;
EditText txtPassword;
```

in your fragment, but it appears you use that function in loginActivity before the fragment is ready. In general, you should be performing null checking too.

Comment: No,it is not that soon, I've entered texts in both fields, username and password and then the function is called

Comment: moved the initialization to `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and it solved the problem. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

First I like your post, full of information. The -1 value to the post should be removed by now.

I think txtUsername (from giveData()) is null because you're returning a new fragment in method newInstance. And the new fragment does not have the reference to the UI. It needs the current fragment in correct Context. Try this:

```
public static LoginTextHolder newInstance() {

    return this;    // return current instance of this fragment
}
```

But normally you don't need to specify newInstance with the empty parameters. The powerful **FragmentManager** could retrieve the current Fragment in context. And it helps that your code is in FragmentActivity.

Meantime, let's try this first.

Comment: `this` cannot be called from a static context. This is what i got. But I solved the exception by moving the initialization to `onActivityCreated()`

Answer (score 1):

There is a good Google link @ [SlidingTabsBasicFragment.java](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic/SlidingTabsBasicFragment.html) that shows good sample related code to the issue brought up in this post.

Code snippet from the webpage:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());

        // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be done AFTER the ViewPager has had
        // it's PagerAdapter set.
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
```

Note:

1. In override onCreateView, it only returns the view from inflater.inflate(... , nothing more.
2. In override onViewCreated, it creates/finds the UI and it does more than that. This method occurs right after onCreateView. In this case from the posted issue, the timing made the difference.
3. From Google, according to [onViewCreated method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)), part of the explanation says:

> This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once they know
>   their view hierarchy has been completely created.

So now I know and will remember...